# How do I delete from two tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

For example,

```
 DELETE table1., table2. FROM table1, table2 WHERE (((table1.[Field1])=table2.[Field1]));
```

Comment: Why cant you just delete one by one?

Comment: There is no ANSI-SQL solution as the SQL standard doesn't allow this (and besides: `[Field1]` isn't a valid identifier in ANSI SQL to begin with). But some DBMS have extensions that would allow you to do that. Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DELETE CASCADE which deletes an element and any other which depends on it.

For example, if you have a Student table, a Course table and a Subscription table which lists all courses a student want to follow, you can delete a student and any entree related to him in the Subscription table with CASCADE.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest nested CURSORs:

```
DECLARE @OuterVar [datatype];
DECLARE @OuterPKey [datatype];
DECLARE @InnerPKey [datatype];

DECLARE OuterCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT table1.[Field1], table1.[PrimaryKey]
FROM table1;

OPEN OuterCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM OuterCursor INTO @OuterVar, @OuterPKey;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DECLARE InnerCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT table2.[PrimaryKey]
FROM table2
WHERE table2.[Field2] = @OuterVar;

OPEN InnerCursor;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @OuterPKey;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE [PrimaryKey] = @InnerPKey;

FETCH NEXT FROM InnerCursor INTO @InnerPKey;

END;

CLOSE InnerCursor;
DEALLOCATE InnerCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM OuterCursor INTO @OuterVar, @OuterPKey;

END;

CLOSE OuterCursor;
DEALLOCATE OuterCursor;
```

This will loop through all the records in table1, and for each record, it will find the records in table2 where the values of table1.[Field1] and table2.[Field2] are the same. Then it will delete both records.